# Animating a Uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, core-animation

Tweetbot has some cool animations added to UITableViewCell's when swiped right that eventually reveal the conversation which got me curious: how do you animate a UITableViewCell to move it away from the normal frame of the tableview?

Also, how might you animate other views that are on top of the tablecell? Like a UIActivityMonitor or fading in and out a button?

I am not looking for answers for when it enters editing mode, or is selected, but rather in general.  Thanks Guys.

Comment: Adding Swipe Gesture to cell and on right swipe,changing the frame of the cell to new frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:tblview];
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tblAim indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

ProjectCell *cell = (ProjectCell *) [tblAim cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell.frame.origin.x!=0)
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{  [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0,cell.frame.origin.y, 320, 60 )];} completion:^(BOOL finish){
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0-10,cell.frame.origin.y, 320, 60 )];} completion:^(BOOL finish){
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0,cell.frame.origin.y, 320, 60 )];}];
                }];
            }];
```

Comment: Any idea about animating views on the contentview of the cell?

Comment: Not tried,but I think you can add gesture to contentview and animate it.